# aggregate two quadratic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I have a quadratic function$$W(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=A\sum_{i} x_i^2+ \sum_{i\neq j} x_ix_j.$$ Denote the input vector as $\textbf{x}$, in quadratic form, $W(\textbf{x})=\textbf{x}^TM\textbf{x}$, where $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    A & 1 & 1 & \dots  & 1 \\
    1 & A & 1 & \dots  & 1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \dots  & A
\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
Now I define a aggregator as 
$$W(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=W(\textbf{x})+W(\textbf{y})$$
Is this aggregator "additive separable" in math language? 
Generally $$W(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\neq W(\textbf{x}+\textbf{y})$$
as $$W(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=A\sum_{i} (x_i^2+y_i^2)+ \sum_{i\neq j} (x_ix_j+y_iy_j).$$ While $$ W(\textbf{x}+\textbf{y})=A\sum_{i}(x_i+y_i)^2+\sum_{i\neq j} (x_i+y_i)(x_j+y_j).$$

Is the aggregator $W(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})$ also "quadratic"? I am not sure about the notion of "quadratic" aggregator here. Can it be written in a quadratic form using $M$ or another symmetric matrix?

Comment: Are you are asking whether $\;W(kx,ky)=W(k(x,y))=k^2W(x,y)\;$ ? Because if you are then the answer is clearly yes.

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks, what you write, in my understanding is "homogeneous", quadratic functions are homogeneous, but is this the general definition of "quadratic" of a aggregator function? How do you write $W(x,y)$ in a quadratic form?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming we're working over the real numbers.  Recall that a quadratic space is a vector space equipped with a quadratic form, typically written (q, V), and that the orthogonal sum of two quadratic spaces $(q_1, V_1)\perp (q_2, v_2)$ is the direct sum of the $V_1, V_2$ as vector spaces but equipped with the new quadratic form $q = q_1+q_2$.

By definition, it's clear that $W(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ is the orthogonal sum of two copies of the quadratic space $W(\mathbf{x})$.  It's easily shown that this is again a quadratic space and that the matrix for the new quadratic form is the following:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
M & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & M
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Because this is a quadratic form, we also get the property mentioned in the comments where $W(k\mathbf{x},k\mathbf{y})=k^2 W(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$.

Comment: thanks, and I guess generally, for $n$ copies, the new matrix is formed by $n$ $M$ matrices on the diagonal?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  In general when dealing with orthogonal sums of quadratic spaces, it's also super nice when you look at what this does to the polynomials; for example, if you know that the first quadratic form is a certain polynomial in $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ and the second in $y_1,\ldots , y_n$, then you just add the first polynomial (in $x_i$) and the second (in $y_i$) to get the resulting new quadratic form.  That's why it works out so nicely with matrices.  You might be interested in looking through the first chapter of the book "Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields" by T.Y. Lam.

Comment: thanks, I will. Do you happen to know the notion of qausi-concavity of such an additive separable aggregator? If I know each $W(\textbf{x})$ is quasi-concave, is the aggregator quasi-concave? How is the quasi-concavity of such an aggregator defined?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much insight into the concavity aspect.  Good luck with your work/search on it though!